# how to do filter search

Tags: android, filter

I got a listview containing eventName, date, time, venue and event description. but i only want to  search for eventName and date. Right now, i only have

```
listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_box);
        arrayA =  new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, event); 

        listview.setTextFilterEnabled(true);  
        listview.setAdapter(arrayA);

         edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

         public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){

             // TODO Auto-generated method stub     

             }  


         public void beforeTextChanged( CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { 
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub       
         }  

         public void afterTextChanged( Editable s){
             {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
                 arrayA.getFilter().filter(s); 

             }
```

that only filter the list not what i want
 is there only way i can do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this by creating your own custom filter. You can get the Array adapter to use your custom filter by overriding the getFilter method

```
public Filter getFilter() {
        filter = new MyCustomFilter();

        return filter;
    }
```

Comment: i am actually new to android, can you give me an example for it ?